# How can I change the CSS padding for just the homepage/frontpage

Tags: css, wordpress

On my [website](https://thespax.com), I added the following code which I had only intended to apply to my posts, like [this](https://www.thespax.com/nfl/estimated-value-isolating-quarterback-performance/).

```
@media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
p {
font-size: 21px;
padding-right: 20%;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-left: 20%;
}
}
```

Obviously, it was applied to all the pages on the website. It's fine on some pages, but the [homepage/frontpage](https://thespax.com) is messed up on computers. If you scroll down, the excerpts (descriptions) below the posts have these margins applied to them.

How can I make the change above only apply to posts and not to the frontpage/homepage? **To be clear, I want to remove these paddings from the homepage/frontpage. I want to keep them on my posts.**

This is one of the suggestions people gave me that didn't work. If I decreased the number from 20%, nothing happened. The margins got bigger if I increased the padding, as if the minimum is set to 20%.

```
.home .posts-loop .entry-summary{
  font-size: 21px;
  padding-right: 20%;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 20%;
}
```

Comment: Please also share the HTML for this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome Ahmed.

The suggestion that people gave you that didn't work, is related to class names (note the point before the names: .home | .ports-loop | .entry-summary . This indicates that are classes).

In your first sample you only use p . This affect to all p html elements.

So, your solution is to add a class to the paragraphs where you want to aply the css rules:

```
<p id="xxxx" name="xxxx" class="SomeClass">
```

And then, in your css code, use .SomeClass {...} to set the rules to apply.

This rules should be applied only in the elements set as class="SomeClass", and not to other elements.

Comment: Thank you very much! This solves my problem perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

For home page/front page just give another custom class name and just give padding to 0 or else you want and write " !important ".For e.g .cstm_home { padding: 0 !important; } . I hope it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way I see around this is to create a different stylesheet for the homepage. I'm not sure if you're using a global stylesheet, if you are, you should remove the line that links the CSS to this page.

A more prudent approach would be to use another type of selector instead of your paragraph tag, put an id in all the paragraphs you would like to style the aforementioned way and use this id or any other selector in your CSS.

Cheers!
I hope this helps....

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is to add a class to the p tag on home page. The HTML should be like

```
<p class="homepagepara">blah blah blah.....</p>
```

And the css will be like.

```
p.homepagepara {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}
```

After you have created the class you can style those pages any way you want. And it will target the home page paragraphs only. Hope this helps. Let me know if you have more questions

Answer (score 0):

I wish you had shared your HTML as well. But a general answer is that you are selecting all the p elements in the html document to have the mentioned paddings. So of course it's applied everywhere on the page.

Solution 1: If they're separate html pages you can link separate stylesheets and include the paddings only in the desired pages.

Solution 2: Be more specific with the css selector. For example if the wrapper div for the posts has the class of `.posts`, write your css as following:

```
.posts p {
  font-size: 21px;
  padding-right: 20%;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 20%;
}
```